# JSF PrimeFaces p:dataTable Not Updating Immediately and Issues with Filtering by Roles

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I am working on a JSF application using PrimeFaces and facing two issues related to p:dataTable:

Data Table Not Updating: When I add a new user through a dialog, the user is successfully saved to the database. However, the p:dataTable on my page doesn't show the new entry until I manually refresh the page. I expected the table to update automatically.

Filtering Issues: In the data table, when filtering by user roles, the filter needs to be applied twice to take effect. Additionally, when I type into any filter field and then delete a character, the filter does not reset as expected. This issue is particularly problematic as it affects the usability of the filtering feature.

Here's the relevant XHTML and Java code:

creating new user:

```
 <p:commandButton value="Create User"
                             oncomplete="PF('userCreateDialog').show()"
                             update=":userForm:userCreateDialog"
                             icon="pi pi-plus"
                             styleClass="ui-button-success"/>

            <p:dialog header="Create User" id="userCreateDialog" widgetVar="userCreateDialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false">

                    <!-- Columns configuration -->


                    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                        <p:commandButton value="Save" action="#{createUserController.doCreateUser()}" oncomplete="PF('userCreateDialog').hide()" update="@form"/>
                        <p:commandButton value="Abort" onclick="PF('userCreateDialog').hide()"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>


            </p:dialog>
```

I expect the user list to update when I click the "Save" button in the dialog.

filtering by names (this works fine but whenever i delete a letter it won't refresh filtered users):

```
<p:dataTable id="usersTable" widgetVar="usersTable" var="user"
                         value="#{userListController.users}"
                         rowKey="#{user.username}" filteredValue="#{userListController.filteredUsers}"
                         emptyMessage="Users Not Found"
                         reflow="true" rows="30" paginator="true" dataLocale="de">
                <p:column headerText="Username" sortBy="#{user.username}" filterBy="#{user.username}" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                    <f:facet name="filter">
                        <p:inputText onkeyup="PF('usersTable').filter()" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.username}"/>
                </p:column>

                 <!-- same for first name etc -->

                <p:column headerText="Roles" filterBy="#{user.roles}" filterMatchMode="in">
                    <f:facet name="filter">
                        <p:selectOneMenu value="#{userListController.selectedRoleName}" style="width:100%">
                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="All" itemValue="#{null}" />
                            <f:selectItems value="#{userListController.availableRoles}" var="role"
                                           itemLabel="#{role.name()}" itemValue="#{role.name()}" />
                            <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{userListController.filterByRole}" update=":userForm:usersTable" />
                        </p:selectOneMenu>

                    </f:facet>
                    <h:outputText value="#{user.roles}" />
                </p:column>
```

I expect the user list to update when I click the "Save" button in the dialog.

this is my java code:

```
@Controller
@Scope("view")
public class CreateUserController {
    // Attributes and Dependency Injection

    public void doCreateUser() {
        // Logic to save user
        userListController.refreshUserList();
        PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("userForm:usersTable");
    }
}
```

```
@Component
@Scope("view")
public class UserListController implements Serializable {
    // ... other fields ...

    private List<Userx> filteredUsers;

    // Method to get users and initialize filtered list
    public Collection<Userx> getUsers() {
        if (filteredUsers == null) {
            filteredUsers = new ArrayList<>(userService.getAllUsers());
        }
        return filteredUsers;
    }

    // Refresh the user list
    public void refreshUserList() {
        filteredUsers = new ArrayList<>(userService.getAllUsers());
    }

    // Filtering logic
    public void filterByRole() {
        // ... logic to filter users by role ...
        PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("userForm:usersTable");
    }

    // Getters and setters for filteredUsers, selectedRoleName, etc.
    
}
```

In the CreateUserController, the doCreateUser method should refresh the user list and update the data table, but it doesn't seem to work as expected. In UserListController, the filterByRole method is intended to filter the users, but the behavior is inconsistent.

Any suggestions or insights into what might be causing these issues or how to resolve them would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: instead of updating the Datatable wrap the datatable in a `p:outputPanel id="XXX"` and update the panel owning the DIV does that make a difference?

Comment: @Melloware unfortunately not

Comment: OK I think there is something wrong with your code can you put together a reproducer using PrimeFaces Test: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test